# How do I parse a JSON string to a C# object using inheritance / polymorphism?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to parse a JSON string to a C# object that could be polymorph.

To sum it up: I don't want to instantiate the root object, but I want to instantiate the inherited object depending on the JSON input.

Here's an example of the C# objects I use:

```
public class Module {
  public string name;
}

public class Wheel : Module {
  public int amount;
  public Wheel(string name, int amount) : base(name) {...}
}

public class Break : Module {
  public double delay;
  public Break(string name, double delay) : base(name) {...}
}
```

And I have this JSON string that is an array containing two JSON objects:

```
[{
  "name":"Wheel",
  "amount":4
},{
  "name":"Break",
  "delay":1.0
}]
```

I want to have this JSON-string deserialized as a C# object (list/array). Each item should be instantiated as a subclass (`Wheel` or `Break`), but since `List` items have to be on the same denominator, the list type has to be of type `Module`.

Comment: what is difference between [your old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272202/litjson-parsing-inherited-object-in-c-sharp) and this question?

Comment: clearer description , old one has been deleted (or at least is in progress)

Comment: Have you tried Newtonsoft library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the [Newtonsoft JSON Library](http://james.newtonking.com/json), you can create some custom converters, as follows:

```
public class ModuleObjectConverter : JsonCreationConverter<Module>
{
    protected override Module Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        // This is the important part - we can query what json properties are present
        // to figure out what type of object to construct and populate
        if (FieldExists("amount", jObject)) {
            return new Wheel();
        } else if (FieldExists("delay", jObject)) {
            return new Break();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private bool FieldExists(string fieldName, JObject jObject)
    {
        return jObject[fieldName] != null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // We don't deal with writing JSON content, and generally Newtonsoft would make a good job of
        // serializing these type of objects without having to use a custom writer anyway
    }
}

// Generic converter class - could combine with above class if you're only dealing
// with one inheritance chain, but this way it's reusable
public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Load JObject from stream
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Create target object based on JObject
        T target = Create(objectType, jObject);

        // Populate the object properties
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }
}
```

You then pass an instance of this helper to Newtonsoft when deserializing:

```
var modules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Module>>(jsonString, new ModuleObjectConverter());
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in one neat swoop. If I'd had to do it, I'd probably do it like this.

```
var json = @"
[{
""name"":""Wheel"",
""amount"":4
},{
""name"":""Break"",
""delay"":1.0
}]";

// Get a list of possible types from the assembly containing Module.
// I don't know of a better way of doing this.
var types = typeof (Module).Assembly.GetTypes();

// Parse the original JSON into an array.
var joList = JArray.Parse(json);

// List I want to populate
var listModule = new List<Module>();

foreach (dynamic token in joList)
{
    string name = token.name;

    // Get the actual type.
    var type = types.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == name);

    // If type is not found then continue.
    if (type == null)
        continue;

    // If type is not a subclass of Module, continue.
    if (!type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Module)))
        continue;

    // Now deserialize that token into the actual type and add it to the list
    listModule.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(token.ToString(), type));

}
```

And ReSharper then converted all that code in the foreach loop into this nifty little one-liner.

```
var listModule = (from dynamic token in joList
    let name = token.name
    let type = types.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == (string) name)
    where type != null
    where type.IsSubclassOf(typeof (Module))
    select JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(token.ToString(), type)).Cast<Module>().ToList();
```

You need http://james.newtonking.com/json for that.