# How to programmatically choose a constructor during deserialization?

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to deserialize a `System.Security.Claims.Claim` object serialized in the following way:

```
{
    "Issuer" : "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
    "OriginalIssuer" : "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
    "Type" : "http://my.org/ws/2015/01/identity/claims/mytype",
    "Value" : "myvalue",
    "ValueType" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
}
```

What I get is a `JsonSerializationException`:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type
>   System.Security.Claims.Claim. A class should either have a default
>   constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked
>   with the JsonConstructor attribute.

After some investigation I finally understand the meaning of *one* in the above message: The JSON deserializer cannot find the right constructor as there are - in the case of the `Claim` type - **multiple constructors with arguments** (although there exists a constructor with arguments matching exactly the above properties).

Is there a way to tell the deserializer which constructor to choose without adding the `JsonConstructor` attribute to that mscorlib type?

Daniel Halan has solved this issue with a [patch to Json.NET a few years ago](http://blog.halan.se/post/Deserializing-objects-with-non-default-constructors-in-JSONNET.aspx). Is there a way to solve this without modifying Json.NET these days?

Comment: Could you post your code + constructors?

Comment: I haven't got time to go into it now unfortunately, but you can override and implement your own `JsonConverter`.  [This previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311635/how-do-i-parse-a-json-string-to-a-c-sharp-object-using-inheritance-polymorphis/27313288#27313288) might help get you started, but you'll need to take it a bit further and read the json fields before calling the constructor

Comment: Thank for the link to your previous answer with your `JsonCreationConverter<T>`!

Comment: link " a patch to Json.NET a few years ago" is broken

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If it is not possible to add a `[JsonConstructor]` attribute to the target class (because you don't own the code), then the usual workaround is to create a custom `JsonConverter` as was suggested by @James Thorpe in the comments.  It is pretty straightforward.  You can load the JSON into a `JObject`, then pick the individual properties out of it to instantiate your `Claim` instance.  Here is the code you would need:

```
class ClaimConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(System.Security.Claims.Claim));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        string type = (string)jo["Type"];
        string value = (string)jo["Value"];
        string valueType = (string)jo["ValueType"];
        string issuer = (string)jo["Issuer"];
        string originalIssuer = (string)jo["OriginalIssuer"];
        return new Claim(type, value, valueType, issuer, originalIssuer);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, simply pass an instance of it to the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` method call:

```
Claim claim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Claim>(json, new ClaimConverter());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7LjgGR

Comment: Glad someone had the time to answer properly :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! (And thanks for fixing the erroneous  namespace in my question! ;-) )

Answer (score 12):

Another approach, which will work for non-sealed classes at least, is to subclass it, but with only the constructor you're interested in:

```
class MyClaim : Claim {
    public MyClaim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer):
        base(type, value, valueType, issuer, originalIssuer){}
}
```

You can then deserialize to this object with no helper classes, and then treat it as the base type.

```
Claim claim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClaim>(json);
```

---

For sealed classes, you could take this approach (pretending for a second that `Claim` is sealed):

```
class MyClaim {
    private Claim _claim;
    public MyClaim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer) {
        _claim = new Claim(type, value, valueType, issuer, originalIssuer);
    }
    public Claim Value { get {
            return _claim;
        }
    }
}

Claim claim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClaim>(json).Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your alternative approaches! I believe there are situations where they are more suitable than a custom converter.

Comment: Better name for class is DeserializableClaim

Comment: Note that Claim properties Type and Value are read only(properties with only get).
If you need both get and set, do not derive by Claim, but use the second option with containment private Claim _claim;

Answer (score 9):

A `ClaimConverter` has been packaged with [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io).

Namespace: `IdentityServer4.Stores.Serialization`

Example of use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value, new IdentityServer4.Stores.Serialization.ClaimConverter());
```

Comment: This is probably the most simple way if you're already using IdentityServer4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @chen-zhe, this was the simplest solution among above posts including accepted answer. 
In my case, I needed to Deserializing entire Clients (Is4 model) including Claims which was just one of the child class of Client.

Here is what I tried and worked out well -

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> Post(Object model)
{
   var clientString = model.ToString();
   Client client = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Client>(clientString, new ClaimConverter());
}
```

Things to note to make this work:

- First you might want to do away with default binding of framework in my case (ASP.NET Core [FromBody] attribute and
- Resolve ClaimCoverter to native Id4 framework library class in IdentityServer4.Stores.Serialization and no need to reinvent the wheel creating your custom JsonConverter suggested above or even [.NET Core Custom Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2) binding approach

Answer (score 1):

Extending [James Thorpe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization/28156852#28156852) we are using DeserializableClaim class to read from appsetting configuration

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Claim cannot be deserialized in default jsonconverter.
    /// to use in Microsoft Configuration it can't be derived from Claim, as properties Type and Value are read-only but for reading from configuration they must have set.
    ///https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization/28156852#28156852
    /// </summary>
    public class DeserializableClaim
    {
        public  string Type { get; set; }
        public  string Value { get; set; }
        public Claim GetClaim
        {
            get
            {
                return new Claim(Type, Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

And the equivalent of `JsonConverted` for the `System.Text.Json`

```cs
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Utilities;

public class ClaimJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Claim>
{
    // Supported properties:
    private const string Issuer = "Issuer";
    private const string OriginalIssuer = "OriginalIssuer";
    private const string Type = "Type";
    private const string Value = "Value";
    private const string ValueType = "ValueType";

    public override Claim Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            throw new JsonException("Expected start of data");

        string? issuer = null;
        string? originalIssuer = null;
        string? type = null;
        string? value = null;
        string? valueType = null;
        
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                if (type is null)
                    throw new JsonException($"Missing property: {Type}");

                if (value is null)
                    throw new JsonException($"Missing property: {Value}");

                return new Claim(type, value, valueType, issuer, originalIssuer);
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                var propertyName = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case Issuer:
                        issuer = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    case OriginalIssuer:
                        originalIssuer = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    case Type:
                        type = reader.GetString(); 
                        break;
                    case Value:
                        value = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    case ValueType:
                        valueType = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new JsonException($"Unexpected property: {propertyName}");
                
                }
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException("Unexpected end of data");
    }
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Claim value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WriteString(Issuer, value.Issuer);
        writer.WriteString(OriginalIssuer, value.OriginalIssuer);
        writer.WriteString(Type, value.Type);
        writer.WriteString(Value, value.Value);
        writer.WriteString(ValueType, value.ValueType);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```