# "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException unable to find constructor to use for types" error when deserializing class

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, deserialization

I am developing an app in `Xamarin` Android. I have a splash screen where I serialize a class and pass it to `MainActivity` using `Intent`. When I try to deserialize it in `MainActivity` I get an error message :

```
"SerializationException unable to find constructor to use for types"
```

Serialization :

```
void LoadData() {
    Currency currency = new Currency(this);
    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    intent.PutExtra("currency", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currency));
    StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Deserialization :

```
cur = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Currency> (Intent.GetStringExtra("currency")); // I get the error here
```

Class constructor :

```
public Currency(Context context) {
    thiscontext = context;
}
```

I began experiencing this problem after I added the parameter `Context context` to the constructor.
What has caused this? How can I solve it?
Is it possible to serialize/deserialize class which has parameters?

Comment: Well what value would you expect deserialization to pass to that constructor? Do you really *need* that parameter in order to deserialize?

Comment: AFAIK, default ctor for Currency class is absent and that's why you are gettting this error; If you creare a default ctor (without parameter), i am sure you will not get this issue

Comment: @JonSkeet  sorry but I didn't get your question, did you mean if I need that parameter in my class?

Comment: @rt2800 Does this mean I can't serialize/deserialize class which has parameters?

Comment: Well how are you *using* that parameter? Why do you need a context?

Comment: @JonSkeet to check if device is connected to network.                      bool IsNetWorkAvailable()
        {
            bool isonline = false;
            ConnectivityManager connectivitymanager = (ConnectivityManager)thiscontext.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo netinfo = connectivitymanager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
            if (netinfo != null && netinfo.IsConnectedOrConnecting)
                isonline = true;
            return isonline;
        }

Comment: So what does that have to do with a `Currency` value that you would serialize and deserialize? You may want to look at separation of concerns here, separating your service from the data it handles.

Comment: @JonSkeet 
 
I need to check if device is connected to network, if it is "currency" will update rates internet, if not it will load last saved rates. I need context in ConnectivityManager connectivitymanager = (ConnectivityManager)thiscontext.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

Comment: @NikaKurdadze: That doesn't sound like it's something the currency value itself should know about. It sounds like something a `CurrencyManager` or similar should know about.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you so much for your support!, can you guide me about how can I make thing like that? How can I connect CurrencyManager to Currency?

Comment: Well we don't have nearly enough information to start redesigning your app for you, but I would encourage you to think about the values you serialize as pretty much *just* values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have an empty constructor in Currency class in order to deserialize it.

Comment: Not really, you could have solutions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28155770/97615

Comment: Noteworthy is that you can have this constructor be private to avoid mis-using it for other purposes.

Answer (score 11):

One other thing might cause this issue is if you have a full linking enabled in your android project. you need to preserve class and members using

```
[Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class Currency
{}
```

Comment: you almost got it correct here... it was the linking type on the option => build iOS

Comment: @Daniel yes Ios has similar behavior. I wrote Android because question was for android. it can be applied for Ios as well

Comment: You're right, this issue seems to also be caused by the most recent Xamarin guidance to enable full linking to get around Xamarin.Forms using a deprecated API in the iOS app.