# What is the recommended way to deserialize an object with several constructors

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have an entity that contains a list of claims (`System.Security.Claims.Claim`, [MS-docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claim(v=vs.110).aspx)). Serialization works all fine but when it comes to deserialization I am stuck because of the following exception:

> Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Security.Claims.Claim. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.

Since this is not my own class I cannot simply add a default constructor, remove all but one constructor or add the JsonConstructor attribute.

Is there any way to tell ravendb/Newtonsoft.Json what constructor to use by e.g. adding a convention for this particular datatype?

If this should not be possible, what would be the best approach? Options that came to my mind:

- Add a custom JsonConverter for this datatype
- Create a wrapper for the Claims class and hide all but one constructor
- Create a custom Claim class and convert it later to MS-Claims

Comment: [Related (dupe?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization/28155770) specifically for `Claim` objects too (caveat, I provided an answer on that one...).  Not sure how it relates to the use of Raven though, so hesitant to flag it for that reason.

Comment: Thanks James. I came across your answer but was really wondering if ravendb can be configured to solve it directly rather than having a separate JsonConverter. However your solution would be my first choice if there should be no option in ravendb itself.