# parsing object with Property List<Claim> and tell the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to use specific constructor for claims?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm using .NET Core with Newtonsoft.Json. I have a `UserModel` class that has a `List<Claim>` property

```
public class UserModel
{        
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to parse the JSON request into this object class like so:

```
public IActionResult Testpost([FromBody]JObject body)
{
    if (body == null) return BadRequest();

    UserModel user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(body.ToString());

    return Ok(user);
}
```

but deserializing JSON into an object like `Claim` class which I don't have access to throws an exception

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Security.Claims.Claim. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Claims

because it is not able to decide on a constructor

According to online sources I can create a custom converter class that can manage the `UserModel` object creation but I would like to avoid this.

Is it possible to deserialize a JSON object into my `UserModel` class and tell the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to use a specific Claim constructor like `Claim(String, String)` for parsing the Claims?

**EDIT:**
as mentioned by @PaulG i have already check the answer for [How to programmatically choose a constructor during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization)

however the accepted solution used Creates a new class that implements the JsonConverter class then manually parses the body of the JObject request. Moreover, the answer shows how to deal with Claims but not with complex objects where claims are nested as properties

reading another solution in the thread it shows how to create a class that directly implements the constructor needed like so:

```
class MyClaim : Claim {
public MyClaim(string type, string value):
    base(type, value){}
}
```

but this will require me to keep note on the difference between Claim and MyClaim when writing my code. the JSON converter may not be able to assume which constructor to use but i should be able to tell it which one. or is it by design and i have to suck it up and write extra code just for this?

because the alternative for me would be something like this:

```
    public IActionResult CreatePublicUser([FromBody]JObject body)
    {

        string Username = body["Username"].ToString();
        string Password = body["Password"].ToString();

        var Claims = body["Claims"].Children();

        List<Claim> UserClaims = new List<Claim>();

        foreach (var c in Claims)
        {

            UserClaims.Add(
                new Claim(
                        c["Type"].ToString(), 
                        c["Value"].ToString()
                        )
                    );
        }

 UserModel NewUser = (new UserBuilder())
            .WithUserName(Username)
            .WithPassword(Password)
            .WithClaims(UserClaims)
            .Build();

 return Ok(NewUser)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically choose a constructor during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a different approach altogether which is a common practice as well. Define a model only for the interaction with client, e.g.

```
public class UserModelWeb
{        
    public List<ClaimWeb> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

These DTO objects will be used only for the data conversion from JSON and never in the business logic layer. Then you can map your web models to the business logic that you will be using later. This will allow you to not be dependent on internal classes when you read external data. I.e. if you suddenly add a new field, it will be populated from external (and probably untrusted) source. This clear separation of concerns will not allow this since you will have to explicitly define a field in a web model.

Example for your case: let's say you will have later an internal field in the database that only you can edit: "InternalNote". If you add that field to the model, anyone can post the data and edit the field while your intention was only to allow yourself to edit it.

Additionally this will solve your problem since you won't need to cast to other classes.

P.S. You can use your class directly in action methods:

```
MyAction([FromBody]UserModelWeb user)
```

It should be deserialized from json right away.