# How to indicate member's constructor in a collection during deserialization by Json.net?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I wish deserialize list by json.net. The inkpoint has a constructor with parameters. The json.net seems does not  automatic use the inkpoint constructor.

I think I should use the IContractResolver Interface or JsonConverter, to indicate use the inkpoint's constructor with parameters. But I just know how to deserialize a Object like this, do not know how to use them in a collection.

Comment: the inkpoint class is provided by microsoft, I can't add a [JsonConstructor] into it. thus I have to use IContractResolve, but I do not know how to use it to a collection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically choose a constructor during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization)  As long as the converter handles a single item (`CanConvert` returns true for that type), then it should work automatically inside a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the JsonConstructor attribute

```
[JsonConstructor]
public Model(int? id, string name, string description)
{
...
}
```

Just make sure the param names match the json

For collections, as long as the json represents an array of objects you have a model for, you can just do something like

```
List<Model> models= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(json);
```

Comment: thanks, but the inkpoint class is provided by microsoft, I can't add a [JsonConstructor] into it. thus I have to use IContractResolve, but I do not know how to use it to a collection.

Comment: One option is to make a wrapper around inkpoint that calls into the base constructor