# C# Newtonsoft Deserialize Custom Object with Claims?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following simple POCO:

```
  public class ApiKey
  {
    public ApiKey(string key, string owner, List<Claim> claims = null)
    {
      Key = key;
      OwnerName = owner;
      Claims = claims ?? new List<Claim>();
    }

    public string Key { get; }
    public string OwnerName { get; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
  }
```

I can create an instance of this object with one claim, and serialize it with Newtonsoft:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(key)
```

And get a serialized ApiKey like this:

```
"{\"Key\":\"94a5b81f-9837-4c5f-9821-3ebaedc6435d\",\"OwnerName\":null,\"Claims\":[{\"Issuer\":\"LOCAL AUTHORITY\",\"OriginalIssuer\":\"LOCAL AUTHORITY\",\"Properties\":{},\"Subject\":null,\"Type\":\"AdminClaim\",\"Value\":\"AdminClaim\",\"ValueType\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string\"}]}"
```

However, if try to deserialize that string with Newtonsoft like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiKey>(serialized_key);
```

I get the following error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Security.Claims.Claim. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Claims[0].Issuer', line 1, position 83.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

When I expect to get back the original object I serialized in the first place. What am I missing to be able to deserialize this object?

Thanks!

EDIT: The Claim object is from System.Security.Claims.Claim.

EDIT 2: I want to be able to serialize/deserialize the entire ApiKey class, not just the claim part.

EDIT 3: I cannot modify the ApiKey class.

Comment: The error is clear, right? Just because a class is serializable when it doesn't have a suitable constructor does not mean it's deserializable without one. It's not a matter of simply copying a block of memory around.

Comment: Problem seems to be Claim class in constructor. If you read the first line of error message, it indicates it

Comment: I am using the System.Security.Claims.Claim class. Any idea how I can get that to deserialize?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically choose a constructor during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to write a custom converter, there is an example for Claim class in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28155770/6881299

Comment: You have to mark your IReadonlyCollection property  with `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(ClaimConverter))]` attribute.

Comment: An other option is to use the `ClaimConverter` included in the `IdentityServer4` library as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645939/10069673

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `Claim` class hasn't any public constructor. The easiest workaround is to create your own Claim class and deserialise into it:

```
class MyClaim : Claim {
    public MyClaim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer):
        base(type, value, valueType, issuer, originalIssuer){}
}

Claim claim = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClaim>(json);
```

Comment: The answer was copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization/28156852#28156852