# How do I add a Claim (or set of claims) to an AppSettings file?

Tags: json, .net, configuration

I have an application that is normally connected to an authentication service that provides an identity for the current user. Often, when I'm travelling or commuting, I don't have internet access and need to work in a local mode. In this environment, I want to hard-code a set of claims into the application using the appSettings file in order to give the current user an identity.

I'm having trouble deserializing the **System.Security.Claims** structure. I'm using the deserialization method found on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155169/how-to-programmatically-choose-a-constructor-during-deserialization/54645939#54645939), but the Configuration system isn't recognizing it. Here's the definition of the class I'm trying to read from the configuration:

```
public class HttpHost
{
    public Uri BaseAddress { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ClaimConverter))]
    public System.Security.Claims Claim { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the actual data:

```
"HttpHosts": [
{
  "BaseAddress": "https://localhost/",
  "Claim": {
    "Issuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
    "OriginalIssuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
    "Type": "http://my.org/ws/2015/01/identity/claims/mytype",
    "Value": "myvalue",
    "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
  },
  "Identifier": "ThetaRex.OpenBook.Desktop.Common.OpenBookHost",
  "Timeout": "00:01:23"
}],
```

How do I get the Configuration system to recognize the custom type converter - ClaimConverter - such that it will work when using it with DI:

```
public HttpHost(IOptions<List<HttpHost>> options)
{
    HttpHost httpHost = options.Value.Find(h => h.Identifier == typeof(T).FullName);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code was tested in visual studio and working properly

```
    var appSettingsSection = configuration.GetSection("HttpHosts");

    HttpHost[] settings = appSettingsSection.Get<HttpHost[]>();
```

UPDATE

if you need to use a special class Claims you can convert this claim to your class Claims using a mapper or manually ( you can add this code to getter or setter as well)

```
var claims=settings[0].ClaimDetails;

settings[0].Claims= new System.Security.Claims { Issuer=claims.Issuer, .... }
```

classes

```
public class HttpHost
{
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Claim")]
    public ClaimDetails ClaimDetails { private get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public System.Security.Claims Claims { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Timeout { get; set; }
}
public class ClaimDetails
{
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string OriginalIssuer { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
}
```